# Kafka Streams Materialized Store Build Error

Tags: java, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I'm trying to build the Materialized.as DSL code here: https://kafka.apache.org/11/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/streams/state/Stores.html

But I'm getting the error

```
incompatible types: org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.Serde<java.lang.Long> cannot be converted to org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.Serde<java.lang.Object>
```

On the line

```
.withKeySerde(Serdes.Long())
```

Does anyone know what might be wrong here?

```
final StreamsBuilder builder = new StreamsBuilder();

   KeyValueBytesStoreSupplier storeSupplier = Stores.inMemoryKeyValueStore("mystore");
   KTable<Long,String> dataStore = builder.table(
     "example_stream",
     Materialized.as(storeSupplier)
             .withKeySerde(Serdes.Long())
             .withValueSerde(Serdes.String()));
```

Comment: Please add code with toplogy/state store building

Comment: Please add the code.

Comment: Apologies, I added the code building the store.

Comment: See [mcve]. Add `builder` definition, and all other code that `builder` uses

Comment: What is the Stream Builder default Key and Value Serde Config?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that `builder.table` does not know the generic type defaulting to `<Object,Object>`. Later, the Serde types don't match. You need to specify the types like

```java
KTable<Long,String> dataStore = builder.<Long,String>table(
    "example_stream",
    Materialized.as(storeSupplier)
        .withKeySerde(Serdes.Long())
        .withValueSerde(Serdes.String()));
```

Answer (score 0):

I cannot say for sure without a code sample, however the error message is very clear. You are specifying to Kafka that the key is of type `Long`. However your key is actually some other Java Object. For example if you had a message with a String key, this code would change to: `.withKeySerde(Serdes.String())`. Check the type of the key and specify the correct `Serde` for that type.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I added the relevant code. I'm having trouble finding fault with it.

Comment: It would also be helpful if you would include a sample key:value message that comes from `example_stream`.