# Kafka Streams WindowStore build error - Serdes<String> incompatible with Serdes<Object>

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

Im trying to use the aggregate function for a Kafka Stream tumbling [window][1].
However, I'm getting this strange build error.

This is how my code looks like -

```
kStreamBuilder.stream(topic, Consumed.with(STRING_SERDE, MYBEAN_SERDE))
            .groupBy((key, value) -> value.id(), Grouped.with(
                    Serdes.String(),
                    MYBEAN_SERDE))
            .windowedBy(TimeWindows.of(Duration.ofMinutes(1)))
            .aggregate( Aggregration::new,(key, value, aggregration) ->
                    {
                        aggregration.count++;
                        return aggregration;
                    },Materialized.as(Stores.persistentWindowStore("asd",Duration.ofMinutes(1), Duration.ofMinutes(1),false))
                    .withKeySerde(STRING_SERDE).withValueSerde(AGGREGRATION_SERDE)
            );
```

This is the error I'm getting in the ".withKeySerde(STRING_SERDE)" part -

java: incompatible types: org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.Serde<java.lang.String> cannot be converted to org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.Serde<java.lang.Object>

Answer (score 1):

Found the solution here - [Kafka Streams Materialized Store Build Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54062509/kafka-streams-materialized-store-build-error)

Here is the updated code -

```
kStreamBuilder.stream(topic, Consumed.with(STRING_SERDE, MYBEAN_SERDE))
        .groupBy((key, value) -> value.id(), Grouped.with(
                Serdes.String(),
                MYBEAN_SERDE))
        .windowedBy(TimeWindows.of(Duration.ofMinutes(1)))
        .aggregate( Aggregration::new,(key, value, aggregration) ->
                {
                    aggregration.count++;
                    return aggregration;
                },Materialized.<String,Aggregration>as(Stores.persistentWindowStore("asd",Duration.ofMinutes(1), Duration.ofMinutes(1),false))
                .withKeySerde(STRING_SERDE).withValueSerde(AGGREGRATION_SERDE)
        );
```